# who can explain CLError more clearly (kCLErrorLocationUnknown, kCLErrorDenied,kCLErrorNetwork ...)?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cllocationmanager

who can explain CLError more clearly?
(kCLErrorLocationUnknown, kCLErrorDenied,kCLErrorNetwork, kCLErrorHeadingFailure, kCLErrorRegionMonitoringDenied, kCLErrorRegionMonitoringFailure, kCLErrorRegionMonitoringSetupDelayed )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better than [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010237-CH2-SW2)?

> **kCLErrorLocationUnknown**
>
> The location manager was unable to obtain a location value right now.
>
> **kCLErrorDenied**
>
> Access to the location service was denied by the user.
>
> **kCLErrorNetwork**
>
> The network was unavailable or a network error occurred.
>
> **kCLErrorHeadingFailure**
>
> The heading could not be determined.
>
> **kCLErrorRegionMonitoringDenied**
>
> Access to the region monitoring service was denied by the user.
>
> **kCLErrorRegionMonitoringFailure**
>
> A registered region cannot be monitored.
>
> **kCLErrorRegionMonitoringSetupDelayed**
>
> Core Location could not initialize the region monitoring feature
>   immediately.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, better than the documentation, which is so vague as to be meaningless in at least two important instances.  kCLErrorLocationUnknown has, in my testing, been a recoverable error.  I have been successful, so far, in ignoring it and moving on.  I do most of my GPS testing on spare iPhones that don't have a service plan, and I will catch kCLErrorNetwork from time to time as well (also recoverable if you have a GPS enabled device).  The others have to do with region monitoring or geocode results, which I don't use and can't speak to, but they seem fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Flight mode seems to generates an kCLErrorLocationUnknown error:

- initialize Location (startUpdatingLocation)
- set accuracy to kCLLocationAccuracyBest
- get some readings ...
- set accuracy to kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
- put device into flight mode, leaving wifi off
- set accuracy to kCLLocationAccuracyBest

You'll find you may quickly get one or two readings, then you get didFailWithError (kCLErrorLocationUnknown,kCLErrorDomain)